# trigger only fired one when i use insert into select

Tags: t-sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bpb_cons_no ON dbo.t_bpb_cons
FOR INSERT
AS
/*
fungsi  : membuat document bon permintaan barang maintenance number secara otomatis`
author  : ryan
*/
declare @new_doc_no varchar(20)
declare @doc_no varchar(20)
--declare @doc_no bigint
--update doc no
SELECT @doc_no = max(cast(substring(doc_no,9,13) as integer)) from t_bpb_cons
IF (@doc_no IS NULL)
BEGIN
set @doc_no = 0
END
PRINT @DOC_NO
SELECT @new_doc_no = cast(@doc_no+1 as varchar(20))
SELECT @new_doc_no = LEFT('BPB/CON/',8+len(@new_doc_no))+@new_doc_no
UPDATE t_bpb_cons SET doc_no=@new_doc_no WHERE [ID]=(SELECT MAX([ID]) AS id from t_bpb_cons)
```

it works fine with single record inserted, but i used Insert into tbl select tblvalue from AnotherTable to insert multiple record it's only affected on the last record...
why ??

Comment: SQL Server presumably (could be Sybase I suppose). What version are you on?

Comment: Also, have you considered splitting the `doc_no` column into two columns (or just one storing the `int` portion) and using a computed column to do the formatting? It would make this a lot easier and get rid of all of the annoying casts to/from strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Insert* statement (even having multiple rows) treated as a single operation, you have to handle by yourself the inserted values in the trigger code.

try this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bpb_cons_no ON dbo.t_bpb_cons
FOR INSERT
AS
/*
fungsi  : membuat document bon permintaan barang maintenance number secara otomatis`
author  : ryan
*/
declare @new_doc_no varchar(20)
declare @doc_no int
declare @row_inserted int

select @row_inserted = count(*) from inserted
--declare @doc_no bigint
--update doc no
SELECT @doc_no = max(cast(substring(doc_no,9,13) as integer)) from t_bpb_cons
IF (@doc_no IS NULL)
BEGIN
set @doc_no = 0
END
WHILE @doc_no < @doc_no + @row_inserted
BEGIN
    PRINT @DOC_NO
    SELECT @new_doc_no = cast(@doc_no+1 as varchar(20))
    SELECT @new_doc_no = LEFT('BPB/CON/',8+len(@new_doc_no))+@new_doc_no
    UPDATE t_bpb_cons SET doc_no=@new_doc_no WHERE [ID] = (SELECT MAX([ID]) AS id from inserted)
    SET @doc_no = @doc_no + 1
END
```